# Split a mathematical expression

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split

I'm separating a string which is a mathematical expression, I want to split every number, operator and parentheses, and send them to an array, this is my code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the expression :");
String infija = in.nextLine();
String separate[] = infix.split("(?=[-+*/%()])|(?<=[^-+*/%][-+*/])|(?<=[()])");
```

but when I enter an expression with m modulus, the code does not separate it.

For example, entering

```
(2/3)+(2%1)
```

the expected result is:

```
[(,2, /, 3,), +,(, 2, %, 1,)]
```

Comment: Can you please include an example of that "expression with m modulus" ?

Comment: this is an example : 2/3+2%1  so the expected result is 2 / 3 + 2 % 1

Answer (score 3):

There's an easier way:

```
String separate[] = infix.split("\\b|(?<=\\D)(?=\\D)");
```

This splits on *word boundary* and between non-digits.

In regex, a "word" char is any digit, letter or underscore. A word boundary is between a word char and a non-word char (and visa versa).

---

Test code:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString("2/(3+2)%1".split("\\b|(?<=\\D)(?=\\D)")));
```

output:

```
[2, /, (, 3, +, 2, ), %, 1]
```

Comment: Question says *"I want to split every number, operator and **parentheses**"*. Too bad the example doesn't have one, so here is another example: `2/(3+2)%1`. Now, that splits to `[2, /(, 3, +, 2, )%, 1]`, which is certainly not right.

Comment: @Andreas Answer now caters for your example.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it,

```
    String myString= "(2/3)+(2%1)";
    String[] result = myString.split("(?<=[-+*/%()])|(?=[-+*/%()])");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

output:

```
    [(, 2, /, 3, ), +, (, 2, %, 1, )]
```

Comment: thanks man, but i also need to separate parenthesis of the mathematical expression

Comment: I dont see parenthesis in your example @Charlesspi check update